# redirection page help -apache

Tags: apache

I have a folder where in there is a .htaccess file with some settings .. so when i try to load the page .its asks for authentication . so when i dont give the user name and passwd . it redirects to a page. i need to know where this redirection settings are there . how to get to the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not terribly clear.

It sounds like you have authentication set up in your `.htaccess` file. If authentication fails, Apache returns a `401 Unauthorized` (or `403 Forbidden`) response. You might try redefining the error pages for those two errors [using the `ErrorDocument` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument).